# Navigation to sub-component of IndexRoute, React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I opened an issue here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2856
and it was suggested I ask the question here instead.

I want to be able to link to a sub-component of my IndexRoute so that if my configuration looks like:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Promote} />
    <Route path="earn" component={Earn}/>
    <Route path="vision" component={Vision}/>
    <Route path="contact" component={Contact}/>
    <Route path="demo" component={Demo}/>
    <Route path="tos" component={Legal}/>
    <Route path="privacy" component={Legal}/>
    <Route path="dmca" component={Legal}/>
</Route>
```

and the component I want to link to is a child component of Promote,  I should be able to do /signup and my index route would load and then scroll/navigate to the desired component instead my Promote component. However I'm not sure how to specify that route inside a route config. Any thoughts?

Some possible ways I've thought of are overriding componentDidMount and checking the path and then scrolling to that component or using an onEnter hook to achieve the same thing, of which the first seems cleaner. I would suspect that there's no real way to achieve this using React Router.

Comment: I'm not really following on your desired Router structure. Can you write like a pseudo-code or explain a bit more please? In particular the subcomponent. What is it called and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `browserHistory` history implementation (rather than `hashHistory`)? If so, you should be able to attach a hash fragment to the url. For example, if the `SignUp` component is located within the `Promote` and the container element for the `SignUp` component had an id of `signup`, you could link to it in other components using code like this:

```
<IndexLink to={{ pathname: '/', hash: '#signup' }}>Sign Up</IndexLink>
```

That link would navigate you to `/#signup`. Then, you could place the following lifecycle methods on the `Promote` component.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.scrollToHash();
  window.addEventListener('hashchange', this.scrollToHash);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('hashchange', this.scrollToHash);
}

scrollToHash() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    let target = document.querySelector(window.location.hash);
    if (target) target.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

The initial invocation of `this.scrollToHash()` in `componentDidMount()` causes the target element to scroll into view when `Promote` initially mounts. The hashchange event listener handles links to the `SignUp` component within the `Promote` component. Speaking of, it's important to note that any links to `SignUp` from within `Promote` should be done using `<a>` tags rather than `<Link>` components. I'm not sure why this is the case. In any event, linking to `SignUp` from within `Promote` should look like this:

```
<a href="#signup">Sign Up</a>
```

[I created a git repo containing some working example code.](https://github.com/bjlewis88/react-router-anchor-example/tree/master) Feel free to play around with it and explore the code, and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hmm this is an interesting. I've sort of succeeded by setting state in my redux store but I like this a lot. I might use this and the store in combo